# Sniff function in scapy for python3.4 does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, scapy

I installed scapy for python3.4 as suggested to me in previous post (link: https://github.com/phaethon/scapy). 
I tried to run this very simple code to show all the wifi networks detected by the program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4

    from scapy import *

    ap_list = []

    def PacketHandler(pkt) :

        if pkt.haslayer(Dot11) :
            if pkt.type == 0 and pkt.subtype == 8 :
                if pkt.addr2 not in ap_list :
                    ap_list.append(pkt.addr2)
                    print ("AP MAC: {} with SSID: {} ".format(pkt.addr2, pkt.info))


    sniff(iface="mon0", prn = PacketHandler)
```

I get the following error when I run the script:

```
python3.4 test_scapy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_scapy.py", line 16, in <module>
    sniff(iface="mon0", prn = PacketHandler)
NameError: name 'sniff' is not defined
```

It seems to me that the function 'sniff' does not work just as in the previous versions, I tried to find the problem without success. If someone knows how to make the function 'sniff' work on this version it would help me a lot.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: In this version, `sniff()` is inside `scapy.sendrecv`. So if you use `from scapy import *`, try calling `sendrecv.sniff()`.

Comment: I am still getting the error: NameError: name 'sendrecv' is not defined

Comment: You should use `from scapy.all import *` instead of `from scapy import *`

Comment: In latest version this syntax does not work, as you may see on the following error I got: ImportError: No module named 'scapy.all'

Comment: There is something wrong with your installation. If you cannot `from scapy.all import *` then obviously it will not work. How did you install python and scapy? Have you changed python library paths, installed local libraries, etc.?